# Update array in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, updatemodel

I have a table menu w/c contains of(recipe_id,ingredient_id,category_id).I was trying to update my ingredients yet it only update 1 ingredient_id. Like this

[image: menu]

Here is my code :

CONTROLLER:

```
 public function save_edit_recipe()
{

foreach($this->input->post('ingredients') as $key => $value)
{
    $menuData[] = array('recipe_id'         => intval($this->input->post('recipe_id')),
                        'ingredient_id'     => intval($value),
                        'category_id'       => intval($this->input->post('recipe_category'))
    );
}
// var_dump($menuData); die();
$this->products_model->updatemenu($menuData);
```

MODEL:

```
  public function updatemenu($data)
{




    foreach($data as $row => $value)
    {
        $this->db->where('ingredient_id', $data['ingredient_id']);
        $query=$this->db->update('menu', $value);

    }


    return $result;


}
```

Comment: Update without where clause?

Comment: What r the values of $this->input->post('ingredients')

Comment: i tried a where clause sir but still it only update one ingredient_id @devpro

Comment: its the name of all the ingredient sir from another table @devpro

Comment: What r the values of this array $this->input->post('ingredients')

Comment: Print_r($this->input->post('ingredients')); chk values either one or more

Comment: actually sir it have many values :) @devpro

Comment: @shikira update code should have `$this->db->where('id', $id);`. It means which field to be updated. Its missing in yours

Comment: i have tried that sir @Abdulla but it still update only 1 ingredient_id :(

Comment: show me that code. (complete). Edit your question

Comment: i edited my model sir @Abdulla

Comment: `print_r($data)` in model and post the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [recipe_id] => 2 [ingredient_id] => 1 [category_id] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [recipe_id] => 2 [ingredient_id] => 2 [category_id] => 3 ) )          @Abdulla

Comment: Can you briefly tell about your question

Comment: well u can see when i tried to print_r($data) it show 2 ingredient_id ryt? i want that to insert in my table and replace the current data in my menu. and the problem is only 1 ingredient_id is updated . see the above photo please :) @Abdulla

Comment: OK i got. One more thing. If there is an update it for one or two. Id will not change. But in yours its change too. Why any reason ??

Answer (score 3):

Remove all data in controller and add in to model.

**In Controller**

```
$this->products_model->updatemenu();
```

**In Model**

```
public function updatemenu()
{
    foreach($this->input->post('ingredients') as $key => $value)
    {
        $menuData = array(
            'recipe_id'         => intval($this->input->post('recipe_id')),
            'ingredient_id'     => intval($value),
            'category_id'       => intval($this->input->post('recipe_category'))
        );
        $this->db->where('ingredient_id', $value);
        $this->db->update('menu', $menuData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check with this. Im not 100% sure. Before check change your data field as it was early too

Comment: @shikira I flagged your comment. You should delete that type of data set publicly.

Comment: I think no need to add ingredient_id in update array bro. Or any other column will use for where clause